# Why doesn't `max-width` work in the following simple example?

Tags: html, css

I've a very primitive example with two `display: inline-block` divs side by side. For some reason `max-width` doesn't apply to these divs and these divs get content size rather whole `max-width` size they're assigned.

Here's full HTML and CSS. Can anyone understand this weird behavior of max-width?

How do I make `#left` and `#right` consume `max-width` without setting constant `width`? I'm doing resposive design.

```css
#left {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#right {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div id="left">
    content left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    content right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it work fine! max-width mean maximum width it can have not like fixed width, in other word the div width will be from 0 to your define value of max-width depend to your content, you can try put more text in both div and see the result

Comment: Thanks now I understand. Do you know how to make `#left` and `#right` consume max-widht even if content is smaller than max-widht? Without using `widht` constant widht?

Comment: You could use `.body{width:100%; max-width:400px;} #left{width:25%;} #right{width:75%}`

Comment: Use `width` doesn't breaks a responsive layout. Use the solution purpose by @Glen (width with percent values)

Comment: `max-width`works exactly as intended in your example. Per default, an inline-block element is as wide as its content makes it, up to 100% width of its parent container. `max-width` only says "no wider than ....px/%/em".

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know how to make #left and #right consume `max-width` even if content is smaller than max-width? Without using width constant width?

I'm not sure whether this meets your need but `flexbox` might be what you are looking for.

```css
.body {
    display: flex;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#left {
    flex: 0 1 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;

}

#right {
    flex: 0 1 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
      <div id="left">
        content left 
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        content right
     </div>
 </div>
```

Note: `#left` and `#right` can shrink if needed but the `flex-basis` sets the *initial* width to the designated value and the `max-width` sets the upper limit.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/457vsegq/)